# How to encrypt MarkLogic server access credentials in gradle properties file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, marklogic, gradlew

I am using storing MarkLogic access credentials in gradle.properties file as a plain text and it used while running Harmonization/ingestion/Corb jobs. As i am adding the credentials in the properties file as a plain text, its visible to everyone who has code access. What is best approach to encrypt these credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply the [gradle-credentials-plugin](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-credentials-plugin) in order to use encrypted values for credentials.

Apply the `nu.studer.credentials` plugin to your Gradle project.

```
plugins {
    id 'nu.studer.credentials' version '3.0'
}
```

- https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Encrypting-passwords
- https://www.marklogic.com/blog/protecting-password-ml-gradle/
- https://help.marklogic.com/News/NewsItem/View/617/protecting-passwords-in-ml-gradle-projects
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtBmH5ce2cU

CoRB also support [encryption/decryption](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/README.md#encryption) of passwords and components of the XCC connectionstring and can be configured with a [**DECRYPTER**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/README.md#DECRYPTER) option, specifying a decrypter class such as [PrivateKeyDecrypter](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/README.md#commarklogicdevelopercorbprivatekeydecrypter) or [JasyptDecrypter](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/README.md#commarklogicdevelopercorbjasyptdecrypter), or [HostKeyDecrypter](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/README.md#commarklogicdevelopercorbhostkeydecrypter).